# Validity condition for Instrumental Variables

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

My professor states the validity condition in the following way:
$W$ (the matrix of instrumental variables) must be such that 
$ \text{plim} \, \frac{W'u}{N}=0$, where $u$ is the error term.
Intuitively, I can see that in some way, this relates to the covariance between $W$ and $u$, but am not entirely convinced.
Moreover, why do we look at this condition in an asymptotic setting? Why not impose mean independence, i.e., $E(u|W)=E(u)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, $Cov(u,W) = 0$ is implied by $E(u|W) = E(u)$ by the [Law of iterated expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306620/conditional-expectation-and-covariance)

Comment: In general, uncorrelated random variables need not be mean independent. Unless you are talking about an asymptotic case when they are normal......?

Comment: I think $\mathrm{Cov}(u,W)=0$ is *implied by* $E(u|W)=0$, not the other way around.

Comment: you are right, I edited this